# ToC-entry – different fontformats for chapter+numbering and its chaptername

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocloft

I have configured my ToC as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\textmd{\emph\chaptername\ }}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\\ }
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{0em}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{A chapter-heading. Great.}
\end{document}
```

This yields the following:

[image: TOC]

This has about everything I want, except for the chapter-number after ›Chapter‹ which is bold. I have not been able to track the format of this so that I can change it. Any idea how I can do this? changing the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)-macro `\cftchapfont` will change the entire entry, but I would just like the ›Chapter‹ and its corresponding number to be emphasized which I have tried with `\cftchappresnum`.

Comment: I don't think that `KOMA` and `tocloft` go well together

Comment: I think this answer over here has you covered:https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227103/140011

Comment: I think Schweinebacke's answer solves the problem most elegantly within `KOMA`-Script, without having to rely on `tocloft`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy to do using KOMA-Script's `\RedeclareSectionCommand` instead of `tocloft`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  tocbreakafternumber,% line break after chapter number
  tocentrynumberformat=\chaptertocnumber,% new format of the chapter number
  tocdynnumwidth,% avoid overfull \hbox message
]{chapter}
\newcommand*{\chaptertocnumber}[1]{\mdseries\itshape\chaptername~#1}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{A chapter-heading. Great.}
\end{document}
```

[image: with chapter only]

If the chapter entries of the appendix should be automatically prefixed with `Appendix` instead of `Chapter` you can use:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[%
  tocbreakafternumber,
  tocentrynumberformat=\chaptertocnumber,
  tocdynnumwidth
]{chapter}
\newcommand*{\chaptertocnumber}[1]{\mdseries\itshape #1}

\let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#1}{%
    \originaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}%
  }{%
    \originaladdchaptertocentry{\chapapp~#1}{#2}% add current "Chapter" or "Appendix" before the number
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{A chapter-heading. Great.}
  \appendix
  \chapter{An appendix-heading}
\end{document}
```

[image: with appendix]

Comment: Yippieyayeah, @Schweinebacke! This is awesome! I just checked the `KOMA`-Script-Guide and studied these features which can handle some things internally without relying on `tocloft`. One thing that may be necessary to adapt: To remove the `\autodot` after ›Chapter‹ (or ›appendix‹) it is possible to add an option while loading the documentclass: `numbers=noendperiod`. This also effects running headlines in pages, which may then be redefined, as I have done with: `\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot\enskip–\enskip}`.